# iPhone/iPad - Breaking universal into iPhone app only

Tags: iphone, ipad, break, universal

I started my Universal app coding that makes the app run on iPhone and iPad.
But later the requirement changed to make the app just for iPhone.
What are the changes to be made and where to change so that my app is no more an Universal application and make sure that it runs only on iPhone. (Ofcourse it can still run on iPad with 2x button on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode 4 it is as simple as clicking your project file in the project navigator and changing Devices under iOS Application target to iPhone. Then what you want to do is remove all resources that only the iPad was using (images, interfaces) to save space. This can be done in the Build Phases tab.There will still be iPad items in places such as the plist file you can remove and you may just want to do a search for iPad in your project to remove any more unwanted references.